transform an exploded data frame into a deeply nested dictionary, with headers
The function I am using to convert my data frame into a nested dictionary strips the column names from the hierarchy, making the dictionary diffictult to naviagte.
I have a large dataframe that looks similar to ths:
exploded_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'school_code': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,  2, 2],
    'school_name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'district_code': [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20,  20, 20],
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023],
    'source': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2','S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2'],
    'enrollment_measure_name': ['M1', 'M2', 'M1', 'M2','M1', 'M2', 'M1', 'M2'],
    'value': [100, 150, 120, 170, 100, 150, 90, 100]
})

I have been trying to use the following function and several variations.
`def frame_to_nested_dict(exploded_df, levels):
    if not levels:
        return exploded_df.groupby('enrollment_measure_name')['value'].apply(list).to_dict()

    # Group by the highest level of keys and recursively build the nested dictionary
    level = levels[0]
    exploded_df = exploded_df.dropna(subset=[level])
    grouped = exploded_df.groupby(level)
    return {
        key: frame_to_nested_dict(group, levels[1:])
        for key, group in grouped
    }`

with
levels = ['school_code', 'school_name', 'district_code', 'year', 'source']
frame_to_nested_dict(exploded_df, levels)

output:
{1: {'A': {10: {2022: {'S1': {'M1': [100]}, 'S2': {'M2': [150]}}, 2023: {'S1': {'M1': [120]}, 'S2': {'M2': [170]}}}}}, 2: {'B': {20: {2022: {'S1': {'M1': [100]}, 'S2': {'M2': [150]}}, 2023: {'S1': {'M1': [90]}, 'S2': {'M2': [100]}}}}}}

The desired output would be:
{
    'school_code': {
        1: {
            'school_name': {
                'A': {
                    'district_code': {
                        10: {
                            'year': {
                                2022: {
                                    'source': {
                                        'S1': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M1': {'value': [100]}
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'S2': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M2': {'value': [150]}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                2023: {
                                    'source': {
                                        'S1': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M1': {'value': [120]}
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'S2': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M2': {'value': [170]}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        2: {
            'school_name': {
                'B': {
                    'district_code': {
                        20: {
                            'year': {
                                2022: {
                                    'source': {
                                        'S1': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M1': {'value': [100]}
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'S2': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M2': {'value': [150]}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                2023: {
                                    'source': {
                                        'S1': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M1': {'value': [90]}
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'S2': {
                                            'enrollment_measure_name': {
                                                'M2': {'value': [100]}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I found the following solution
def fold_dataframe(df):
columns = df.columns.tolist()
if len(columns) < 2:
    return df
columns = df.columns.tolist()
grouped = df.groupby(columns[:-1], as_index=False).agg({columns[-1]: list})
grouped[grouped.columns[-1]] = grouped.apply(
    lambda row: {columns[-1]: row[columns[-1]]}, axis=1)
grouped[grouped.columns[-2]] = grouped.apply(
    lambda row: {row[columns[-2]]: row[columns[-1]]}, axis=1)
grouped.drop(columns=[grouped.columns[-1]], inplace=True)
return grouped

def fold_dataframe_loop(df):
original_columns = df.columns.tolist()
for _ in range(len(original_columns)):
    df = fold_dataframe(df)
return df

The first function takes the values of the column in position -1 (far right column), groups them, then sets them as a dictionary with the key being the column name and the values being the row values of the grouped column.
The next step is to append the values from the updated column to the values of the column in the next position. Again setting the data as a dictionary with key of the column name in position -2 and the values from the data frame row in column -1.
The second function then loops through the first function for each column until there is only one column.
The resulting structure is technically still a data frame, but it suits my needs and could easily be moved into a true dictionary structure from this point.

You could create a recursive function that returns a dictionary.  Recursively creating dictionaries for groups in a pandas groupby.
This function will keep recursively calling itself until the level_list is empty (at which point, there should only be a pandas.Series with a single level (in this case "enrollment_measure_name").
def recursive_dict(level_list: list, ser: pd.Series) -> dict:
    # check if anything in level_list
    if level_list:
        # pop first item in list
        lvl = level_list.pop(0)
        # return dictionary with key as level name, and values as a
        # dictionary of all unique level values as keys
        # values are recursively calling this function
        return {
            lvl: {
                grp: recursive_dict(
                    ser=grouped_ser.droplevel(lvl),
                    level_list=level_list[:]
                )
                for grp, grouped_ser in ser.groupby(level=lvl)
            }
        }
    # if list is empty, return final dictionary
    return {ser.index.name: ser.to_frame(name="value").to_dict(orient="index")}


def to_nested_dict(df: pd.DataFrame, nest_levels: list) -> dict:
    # initial groupby to create series with levels as index, values as list
    agg = (
        exploded_df
        .groupby(
            nest_levels + ["enrollment_measure_name"]
        )
        ["value"]
        .agg(list)
    )
    # create copy of nest_levels
    lvl_list = nest_levels[:]
    lvl = lvl_list.pop(0)
    # call recursive dictionary for all groups when grouping by first level
    return {
        lvl: {
            grp: recursive_dict(
                ser=grouped_ser.droplevel(lvl),
                level_list=lvl_list[:]
            )
            for grp, grouped_ser in agg.groupby(level=lvl)
        }
    }

out_dict = to_nested_dict(exploded_df, levels)

